# Substitute part of file to path of current directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the following file min.conf as shown below. I need to change the path directory to the current one in the file.

Input file (min.conf)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH  --workdir=/work/LAS/input

myNAMD2=$(which namd2)
myWork=/work/LAS/input
```

I have the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="min.conf"

#While loop to read line by line
while IFS= read -r line; do
    #If the line starts with ST then set var to yes.
    if [[ $line == '#SBATCH  --workdir='* ]] || [[ $line == 'myWork='* ]] ; then

    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Desired output(min.conf) :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH  --workdir=/work/input23

myNAMD2=$(which namd2)
myWork=/work/input23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. Point to be noted here `PWD` is a shell variable and then passing it to `awk` by assigning it to an `awk` variable.

```
PWD=`pwd`
awk -v pwd="$PWD" '
/mywork/{
  sub(/=.*/,"=" pwd)
}
/SBATCH/{
  sub(/workdir=.*/,"workdir=" pwd)
}
1
' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp && mv temp Input_file`

Comment: I need to change the Sbatch line as well.

Comment: @shome, please check now?

Comment: Showing this error : awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /mywork/{sub(/=.*/,"=" pwd)} >>>  /SBATCH/{/workdir=.*/, <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
 extra )

Comment: @shome, sorry typing on cell, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

**`sed`** could do somewhat you want:

```
sed -E '/^(a|b)/s:c:d:g'
```

- `/^(a|b)/`: for all lines starting with `a` or `b`.
- `s:c:d:g` : replace all `c` with `d`.

So, as for changing the path to the current one:

```
sed -E '/^(#SBATCH --workdir=|myWork=)/s:=\/.*\/:='$PWD'\/:'
```

- `/^(#SBATCH --workdir=|myWork=)/`: for all lines starting with `#SB..`
- `s:=\/.*\/:=\/'$PWD'\/:`: replace dir name with current working dir
- `$PWD`: in `bash`, it is your current working dir; `$(pwd)` is also the same

Finally, if you want **`sed`** edit your **`min.conf`** file:

```
sed -i~ -E '/^(#SBATCH --workdir=|myWork=)/s:=\/.*\/:='$PWD'\/:' min.conf
```

- `sed -i~`: edit the file, and make backup